# using ingress to expose dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

we have started using Kubernetes lately.

since we want to use the dashboard and we prefer not using kubectl proxy command I was wondering how to allow dashboard for all external browsers.

I found that ingress might be helpful in it and provide a solution.

does any one know how to implement that dashboard access via ingress?

many thanks

Comment: Hi @eran, If you want to expose it to public then you need to use `type=LoadBalancer` in Service File.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi , thanks for the reply. I am still new to Kubernetes so you can you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: Hi, As recommended It's not good idea to expose the dashboad to the public since other people can access the cluster which is not secure. However If you still want to do it than [k8s-dashboard](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml). In the service file we need to  use type loadbalancer [service-loadbalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty straightforward thing to, assuming you have ingress operational already. We expose couple of internal services like grafana or prometheus over ingress with basic auth security enabled.

Simply create an Ingress in your kube-system namespace that will point to your dashboard service. If you use official community nginx ingress that take advantage of [annotations](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/annotations.md) to set up ssl, auth etc.