# Deploying Kubernetes Dashboard in Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

I'm following this documentation for deploying Kubernetes Dashboard: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

Question # 1:
The instructions are only available to run the dashboard locally. Is there any tutorial to deploy it in Cloud (Azure, AWS)? If not, do we have to manually expose a load balancer / ingress in front of the dashboard service?

Question # 2:
The instructions mentions to run `kubectl proxy` in order to enable access to dashboard. If deploying to cloud, do we need to run that as a process in the background?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but infrastructure management, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). --- Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: I believe the answer to my question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461041/how-to-enable-kubernetes-dashboard-via-nodeport?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957413/how-to-access-kubernetes-dashboard-from-outside-network?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887862/using-ingress-to-expose-dashboard?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 1,
You can deploy this dashboard to a cloud of course, for AWS you could set up eks or ec2 instance and deploy you application or this dashboard directly.

You will need to set up a service, NodePort or Load balancer. Using you VM IP as IP and NodePort as the port exposes for the outside world, or if you decide to create a load balancer, use the endpoint of the service `kubectl get endpoints -n <service_namespace>` and load balancer port.

For question 2 I'm not sure about proxy, maybe my answers for question 1 is enough. But documentation knows better.